Equivalence of the Definition of closed immersion and closed subscheme
In wedhorn and Görtz‘s algebraic geometry book Algebraic Geometry I:Schemes page 86 I found the following definition.
(1)A closed subscheme of $X$ is given by a closed subset $Z\subset X$ and an ideal of sheaf $\mathscr J\subset \mathscr O_X$ such that $Z=${$x\in X:(\mathscr O_X/\mathscr J)_x\neq 0$} and $ (Z,(\mathscr O_X/\mathscr J)|_Z) $ is a scheme.
(2)A morphism $i:Z\rightarrow X$ of schemes is called a closed immersion, if the underlying continuous map is a homeomorphism between $Z$ and a closed subset of $X$, and the sheaf homomorphism $i^b:\mathscr O_X\rightarrow i_*\mathscr O_Z$ is surjective.
If we identify $Z$ with its image, then we should be able to prove these two definitions are equivalent. But unfortuantely I do Not know how to show either implication.
$‘\Rightarrow‘$ The first half of (2) can be easily seen but how to show the induced morphism on sheaves are surjective.
$‘\Leftarrow‘$ We First Need to construct such ideal of sheaf $\mathscr J$. My idea is to define $\mathscr J(U):=ker(\mathscr O_X(U)\rightarrow i_*\mathscr O_Z(U))$ but I do not know how to show it is a sheaf of ideal. It is not difficult to show $\mathscr J$ is a presheaf. And the locality is also not difficult. But I do not know how to show the gluing axiom. Let $s_i\in \mathscr J(U_i),\forall i$, then it means $i^b_{U_i}(s_i)=0,\forall i$ then by sheaf axiom of $\mathscr O_X$ there exists $s\in \mathscr O_X(U)$ such that $s|_{U_i}=s_i$ but such $s$ does not necessarily lie in $\mathscr J(U)$. Even if this is true I still have no idea how to show $Z=${$x\in X:(\mathscr O_X/\mathscr J)_x\neq 0$} and $ (Z,(\mathscr O_X/\mathscr J)|_Z) $ is a scheme.
Sorry I am rather new in algebraic geometry and I know this question should be easy. If possible, please write idea in detail but any help and hints will be helpful. Thanks.

If $F$ and $G$ are two sheaves and $\varphi : F \rightarrow G$ is a morphism of sheaves, then $U \mapsto Ker(\varphi(U))$ is a sheaf.... the "sheaf" issue arises only when you consider the "Image"... https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/612552/how-to-show-that-a-presheaf-kernel-of-a-morphism-of-sheaves-is-a-sheaf
